# Javascript Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have been trying for days to get this code to work right in Javascript on Conditional statements. I'm just lost and can not get it to work right. It needs to meet the following conditions using a prompt to get the input from user

1. If the user tries to get a beverage without placing their cup on the
   tray, display “Please place your cup on the tray.”
2. If it is the custom refillable cup, display “Custom Refillable
   cup: Please make your selection.”
3. If it is the custom
   non-refillable cup AND it is the first time using it, display
   “Custom Non-Refillable cup: You have one fill remaining; Please make
   your selection.”
4. If it is the custom non-refillable cup AND it is NOT the first
   time using it, display “Custom Non-Refillable cup: You have zero
   fills remaining; Please leave.”
5. If it is not either of the custom cups, display “This is an
   invalid cup; Please leave."

It asks: Did you put cup on tray? If I say: Yes It says Please make selection. If I say no: it says please put cup on tray.
THEN
it asks: do you have refil cup?
if i say: yes
it says custom refil cup make selection
closes out
if i said: no
it asks do you have nonrefill cup?
if i say: yes
it asks : is it first time use?
if i say no
it says it will say please leave zero refils
closes out
if i say yes
it says one refill remaining please choose
THEN
if i say no to both the non refill and the refill
it says invalid cup please leave
closes out

the problem i'm having now is when you say NO to REFILL and then say NO to NON REFILL it needs to say wrong cup please leave
and the other problem is
when you say yes to REFILL Cup
it displays the right message saying please make your selection
when you hit okay it doesnt close it continues and asks if you have NON refill cup

My code so far :

```js
let thecup = window.prompt("Did you place the cup on the tray?", "");   
if (thecup === "yes") {
    alert("Please choose your cup");
    } 
else {
    alert("Please put cup on the tray");
    }
        
//If it is the custom refillable cup, display “Custom Refillable cup: Please make your selection.”

let refillcup = window.prompt("Do you have a refillcup?");
if (refillcup === "yes") {
    alert("please make your selection")
    }
else {
    window.prompt("Do you have a Non-Refill?", "");
    }
        
let nonrefillcup = window.prompt("is it first time use?");
if (nonrefillcup === "yes") {
    alert("one refill remaining");
    } 
else {
    alert("Zero remaining refills");
    }
```

here is the right code

```
alert("Please put cup on the tray.")

let theCup = window.prompt("Did you place the cup on the tray? (type yes or no.)");
if (theCup === 'yes') {
    alert("Please choose your cup.")
}

let yourCup = window.prompt("Do you have a Refill cup or a NonRefill cup?");
if (yourCup === 'yes') {
    alert("Please choose your cup");

  let refillCup = window.prompt("Do you have a refill cup? (Answer must be yes or no.)");
  if (refillCup === 'yes') {
    alert("please make your selection");
  } else {
        let firstUse = window.prompt("Is it the first time use? (Answer must be yes or no.)");
    if (firstUse === 'yes') {
      alert("one refill remaining");
    } else {
      alert("You have zero refills remaining. Please leave.")
    }
  }
} else {
    alert("Wrong Cup. Please leave.")
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is with your code - what isn't working about it?

Comment: @lena Not sure why you changed the bracket layout in the edit, your version makes it harder to follow

Comment: so when it asks if you have a refill cup when you say yes it displays the right message but the right after it says zero remaining refils and thats wrong it should just end when you say yes and display the message please make your selection.
the second problem is when you hit no and then it display do you have nonrefillable cup and you say i think either yes or no thats where the code messes up i dont think it says anything

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71200098/edit) to explain how this is not working. Comments must be considered temporary and may be removed at any time

Comment: It asks: Did you put cup on tray? If I say: Yes It says Please make selection. If I say no: it says please put cup on tray.
THEN 
it asks: do you have refil cup?
if i say: yes
it says custom refil cup make selection and closes 
if i said: no
it asks do you have nonrefill cup?
if i say: yes
it asks : is it first time use?
if i say no
it says it will say please leave zero refils
if i say yes
it says one refill remaining please choose
THEN
if i say no to both the non refill and the refill
it says invalid cup please leave

Comment: You aren't saving the result of any of the `window.prompt` calls anywhere except for the first two, so you keep checking the old values.

Comment: You should think about nesting your `if` statements: `if (a = 'yes') { if (b = 'yes') { /* a & b are yes */ } else { /* a is yes, b is no */ } } else { /* a is no & b hasn't been asked */ }`  (where 'no' is technically a 'not a yes' result, but trying to keep it simple here)

Comment: i was trying to nest but my brain is just confusing myself at this point

Comment: Sometimes it's best to take a break from the problem and come back to it. Then try to think about all the conditions that need to be satisfied following just one branch of the problem.  Then, how might you change that slightly to satisfy another branch of answers.  Etc.

Comment: i know just my project due tomorrow and ive been working on it all week i've literally tried 8 others ways my js script has like 20 other tries ive commented out some work somewhat some didn't. i'm not sure if i am doing this the complicated way or what but you are right cause every time i walk away and come back to it i do have progress and get farther in the code. just running out of time.

Comment: And as CherryDT points out, you have a number of `window.prompt()` statements later in the program that don't record the user's answer.  You'll need that to make the decisions based on what they wrote

Comment: okay i just edited it and i think i almost got it i feel im so close. now the only problem is after you say yes to if you have refil cup the answer comes back right but still right after it continues on and asks if you have non refil cup

Comment: and i just need to add the last part where if both questions are no then it says you have invalid cup

Comment: thank you all for the help it is helping

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly, I think this is a possible solution:

```
alert("Please put cup on the tray.")

let theCup = window.prompt("Did you place the cup on the tray? (Answer must be yes.)");

if (theCup === 'yes') {
    alert("Please choose your cup.")

  let refillCup = window.prompt("Do you have a refill cup? (Answer must be yes or no.)");
  if (refillCup === 'yes') {
    alert("please make your selection");
  } else {
    let firstUse = window.prompt("Is it the first time use? (Answer must be yes or no.)");
    if (firstUse === 'yes') {
      alert("one refill remaining");
    } else {
      alert("You have zero refills remaining. Please leave.")
    }
  }
} else {
    alert("Your cup must be on the tray. Please leave.")
}
```

Comment: yeah that's not right there are two cups one cup is the REFILL cup and the other is a NONREFILL cup. if the refill cup is no: then it asks about the nonrefill cup. but if the REFILL cup is yes then it says please choose your drink and closes out

Comment: so when it asks me first if i have refill cup then i say no then it asks me 
if i have a NON refill cup 
- if i say no that i do not have NON refill cup  >>> it says wrong cup please leave
-if i say yes that i do have NON refill cup >>> it asks if it is my first time using
- if i say yes >>> it says one refill remaining
-if i say no >>>> it says zero remaining refills

Comment: I think I now understand the question. I updated the code. Hope that helps. (There are arguably cleaner ways to write this code with `return` statements, but I think this is the answer you're looking for.)

Comment: okay that code is almost right but the only problem is when you say no if you have a REFILL CUP it needs to ask you if you have a NON REFILL CUP and then it asks if its your first time and then if both the refill cup and NONREFILL cup are no it goes to say WRONG CUP PLEASE LEAVE

Comment: Is there a third kind of cup? To get to that point in the code, the user must say that their cup is on the tray, and they must say that they do not have a refill cup. So they must have a non-refill cup?

Comment: the first part with the cup on the tray doesn't really matter what matters is
Do you have refill cup?
yes
>>> Please make selection
*CLOSES out/ends code*

Do you have refill cup?
no 
Do you have NON REFILL CUP?
yes
>>>is it your first time use?
yes
>>> you have one refill remaining
** CLOSES OUT

>>>Do you have refill cup?
no 
>>>Do you have NON REFILL CUP?
yes
>>>is it your first time use?
no
>>> you have no refill remaining please leave
** CLOSES OUT

>>>Do you have refill cup?
no 
>>>Do you have NON REFILL CUP?
no
>>>> wrong cup please leave
** CLOSES OUT

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer believe I understand the question. I hope you're able to get the support you need.

Comment: there are two cups. The Refillable Cup and then the NonRefillable cup. The refillable cup you can refill so it doesn't ask if it's the first time use. The non refillable cup asks if it is the first time use and if you say no then it tells you you can not get any refills because it's the nonrefillable cup. and if you don't have neither cups then you have to leave its the wrong cup

Comment: 1.refill cup
-if yes then get your drink
-if no then continue to the next question
2. nonrefillable cup
-if non refillable cup is first time use then get your drink
-if non refillable cup is not first time use then leave
3. if neither of the cups are the refillable or the nonrefillable then please leave.

Comment: Could we start by asking if the user if they have a cup?